# How I can get values for function?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm stuck with c++. I'm new at this, and I'm confused. totalGrade gives the sum of 5 grades received by the student. But I couldn't calculate this total grade. I can't access the values in the array in the function. How to access values in an array

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student {
    public:
    void takeNotes(){
        int nA1[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            cin>>nA1[i];
        }
    }
    int totalGrade(){
      int totalN=0;
      for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
      // I stayed at this stage 
      }

    }
}
;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  Student * students = new Student[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
  students[i].takeNotes();
  }
  int total = students[0].totalGrade();
}
```

Comment: `nA1` is only defined in the context of `takeNotes` so the array stops existing after `takeNotes` returns. You need to move the array to the class' scope so that it exists for the entire lifetime of the `Student` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is local to `takeNotes()`, so `totalGrade()` can't access it. You need to make the array be a data member of the `Student` class instead, eg:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    int nA1[5];

public:
    void takeNotes(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            cin >> nA1[i];
        }
    }

    int totalGrade(){
        int totalN = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            totalN += nA1[x];
        }
        return totalN;
    }
};

int main(){
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    Student * students = new Student[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        students[i].takeNotes();
    }
    int total = students[0].totalGrade();
    ...
    delete[] students;
}
```

Comment: I get the point I missed. I always defined my array variable in another function. that's why I couldn't get access. I'm just getting used to c++ thank you for the answer